# MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mysql.data

Here is the code that connects to MySql and attemps to query data, and these are the errors i'm getting:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   MySqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings)
>
> MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()

```
public async Task<List<Store>> getStores(double lat, double lng)
    {
        List<Store> stores = new List<Store>();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();   // the code blows up here from time to time

            // request to return nearby stores
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Stores WHERE ABS(latitude- @latitude) < 0.006 AND ABS(longitude - @longtitude) < 0.006", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@latitude", lat));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@longtitude", lng));
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            // MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    stores.Add(new Store()
                    {
                        id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                        address = reader["address"].ToString(),
                        latitude = Convert.ToDouble(reader["latitude"]),
                        longtitude = Convert.ToDouble(reader["longitude"])
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return stores;        
    }
```

Comment: Check the code, your connectionstring might not have the same port which is used by your mysql installation.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta I actually do

Comment: Are you able to use the same connectionstring's setting from Workbench or SQLYog, If yes, It might be a Firewall.